# Prestashop classic theme _dev npm run watch say error

Tags: npm, themes, prestashop

i'm new to prestashop theme development.

i try to setup the classic theme from prestashop github repo.

i go into _dev and run "npm install"

after that i run "npm run watch" but i get the following error:

```
    npm run watch

> prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0 watch C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\prodet\_dev
> webpack --progress --colors --debug --display-chunks --watch

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active
webpack is watching the files…

(node:9136) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
 77% module and chunk tree optimization bound C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:824
                throw new Error(
                ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:824:9)
    at C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\prodet\_dev\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\index.js:260:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\prodet\_dev\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\index.js:255:11)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at Compilation.seal (C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1213:27)
    at C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:547:17
    at eval (eval at create (C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1064:12
    at C:\laragon\www\PrestaShopDev\themes\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:980:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --progress --colors --debug --display-chunks --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-09T10_24_12_727Z-debug.log
```

how can i fix this?